# Trigger fb:login-button with other button Javascript

Tags: facebook, button, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-login

I want to trigger the `fb:login-button`:

```html
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

with a second button. Why? I can't adjust the css of the Facebook and I want a fancy button with a custom image to replace it. My big problem is that I don't know what's the ID of the FB-button, and I can't give it one.

My wrong code:

```html
<script>
    function Ffirst()
    {
    alert("first");
    $("fb:login-button").click(); 
    //$("fb:login-button").trigger("click"); //doesn't work eiter
    }
</script>

<input type="submit" onclick="Ffirst()" name="savebutton" id="first" />
<fb:login-button show-faces="true" width="200" max-rows="1"></fb:login-button>
```

*FTR:*
This is what happens when I press `the fb:login-button`

```js
FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
    // Here we specify what we do with the response anytime this event occurs. 
    if (response.status === 'connected') {
          testAPI();
    }

    } else if (response.status === 'not_authorized') {
      FB.login();

    } else {
          FB.login();
    }
  });

  // Load the SDK asynchronously
  (function(d){
   var js, id = 'facebook-jssdk', ref = d.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
   if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
   js = d.createElement('script'); js.id = id; js.async = true;
   js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js";
   ref.parentNode.insertBefore(js, ref);
  }(document));
```

Comment: Why don't you use Facebook javascript sdk for login and other purpose. I can help you if you wanna use fb javascript sdk for your website.

Comment: [You are not allowed to customize any appearance of the Facebook social plugins](https://www.facebookbrand.com/dos-donts). You'll need to implement the login process with the JavaScript SDK. If you're using the SDK - you can use any button you wish.

Comment: Mmh, I think I am using it? I use a lot of functions listed in here (https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/javascript/). I just didn't include the FB.init code into my sample here (it's included in my application though). Do you want me to add it here?

Comment: You are using the SDK to detect when someone clicks on the login button (`authResponseChange`). Rather use the SDK to initiate the login process. Create a button that when clicked triggers the `FB.login()` function.

Comment: @Lix Can I still keep the response.status then? Because they are important for my original code (this is just an abstract).

Comment: You can leave the current code dealing with `FB.Event.subscribe`. That code will still work no matter how the user logs in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Answer by @Lix in code:

```html
<input type="submit" onclick="FB.login()"/>
```